# Add string value every-time it is called.

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, event-dispatching

When my function `buildingBuilt` is called, it is dispatching an event like so:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("Built"));
```

I've got, in my Toolbar.as a listener that triggers a timer when he heard "built".

Every 10 second my string "money" is dropping 500.

**Toolbar.as**

```
drop500=new Timer(10000);
drop500.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, dropMoney);
addEventListener("Built", timerMoney, false, 0, true);

private function timerMoney(event):void{
            drop500.start();

}

private function dropMoney(event):void {
   money.text = String( Number(money.text ) - 500 );
}
```

Question : The event "Built" is dispatched by other function. Is it possible to add -500 every-time "Built" is heard ?

So, 
if "Built" is dispatched once : "money" is dropping 500 every 10 sec,
if "Built" is dispatched twice : "money" is dropping 1000 every 10 sec
and so on.

Comment: What is your problem after running this code?

Comment: No errors, but the problem is that if the timer is already running, dispatching the event "Built" a second time do NOt add dropMoney a second time. (there is still -500 every 10 seconds and not -1000 every 10 seconds).

Comment: You are starting the timer every time `built` event is dispatched and never stopping the timer. Why?

Comment: cause I want the function dropMoney to be called every 10 sec and never stops. (-500 during all the games every 10 sec)

Comment: (and -1000 if the event "Built" has been called twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your code like so,

```
  var moneyDropper:int = 0;

  private function timerMoney(event):void {

     if(moneyDropper == 0)
     {        
         drop500.start();            
     }
     else
     {
         moneyDropper += 500;
     }
  }

  private function dropMoney(event):void {
      money.text = String( Number(money.text ) - moneyDropper);
  }
```

Comment: the answer before your edit was working great (just had to add moneyDropper += 500; after the drop500.start();  THANKS !